# Error while producing a boxplot with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to reproduce an example saw in the manual of PGFPLOTS v1.9:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1cm]
\addplot+[
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker=42, lower quartile=45,
median=47,
upper quartile=47.5, upper whisker=48,
draw relative anchor=0.5, }, ]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] { 40\\ 34\\ 56\\ };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/boxplot prepared'
```

I updated texlive today and my log says

```
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10
```

Is the code too old for my version?

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Ignasi good, it works. Actually the manual reported it but it was not very clear, in my opinion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Box Plots` is a subsection of `Statistics` section in [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots.pdf) documentation. Therefore you need to include

```
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}
```

to your preamble to draw `Box Plots` or `Histograms`.

Not related with your question but your preamble:

- includes `\usepackage{caption}` twice.
- includes `\usepackage{tikz}` which is already loaded by `pgfplots`.
- `tikz`, `tcolorbox` and `pgfplots` load `xcolor` which provides more facilities than `color`.